# Studying convergence of a function.

Tags: calculus, integration

Lets say I have a function $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\sqrt{x}\tan(x^2)}{\ln(1+x^{\frac{2}{3}})}$ and I need to determine its convergence.

Is my reasoning that if the function is monotonous on $]0,1]$ and is can be developed as when $\lim \rightarrow 0$
$$
\frac{\sqrt{x}\tan(x^2)}{\ln(1+x^{\frac{2}{3}})} \sim x^{\frac{11}{6}} \rightarrow_{x\to0}0
$$
Means that the integral is convergent?
Is there anything I should add to my explanation if intend to justify my answer such as that one in my test paper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all $ x\overset{f}{\mapsto}\frac{\sqrt{x}\tan{\left(x^{2}\right)}}{\ln{\left(1+x^{\frac{2}{3}}\right)}} $ si continious on $ \left]0,1\right] $, and $ \frac{\sqrt{x}\tan{\left(x^{2}\right)}}{\ln{\left(1+x^{\frac{2}{3}}\right)}}\underset{x\to 0}{\sim}x^{\frac{11}{6}}\underset{x\to 0}{\longrightarrow}0 $, Thus $ f $ can be extended to a continuous function on $ \left[0,1\right] $, which means $ f $ is a piecewise continuous function on $ \left[0,1\right] $, hence $ f $ is integrable on $ \left[0,1\right] \cdot $